# Select rows that DO NOT have a SINGLE pair of two columns

Tags: mysql

consider this table: ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd313a/4 courtesy of @Michael Berkowski ))

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  idTransactions INT,
  idMemberCard INT,
  amountFinal FLOAT,
  idAccount INT,
  dateTransaction DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO `transactions` (`idTransactions`, `idMemberCard`, `amountFinal`, `idAccount`, `dateTransaction`) VALUES
(131532,    64924,  20.00,  292,    '2015-07-22 10:59:53'),
(131533,    64924,  -5.00,  292,    '2015-07-22 11:00:03'),
(131534,    64925,  12.00,  292,    '2015-07-22 11:01:07'),
(131535,    64925,  -3.00,  292,    '2015-07-22 11:01:13'),
(131539,    64926,  80.00,  292,    '2015-07-22 11:03:06'),
(131540,    64926,  12.50,  292,    '2015-07-22 11:03:18'),
(131541,    64926,  -4.90,  292,    '2015-07-22 11:03:31'),
(131542,    64927,  37.50,  291,    '2015-07-22 11:04:28'),
(131543,    64927,  -4.50,  291,    '2015-07-22 11:04:35'),
(131544,    64928,  18.00,  291,    '2015-02-22 11:05:03'),
(131545,    64928,  -5.00,  291,    '2015-03-22 11:05:09'),
(131546,    64929,  5.00,   291,    '2015-01-22 11:05:51'),
(131547,    64929,  10.00,  291,    '2015-02-22 11:05:55'),
(131548,    64929,  3.00,   291,    '2015-03-22 11:06:00'),
(131549,    64929,  -2.50,  291,    '2015-04-22 11:06:05'),
(131550,    64926,  -4.50,  291,    '2015-07-22 11:07:38'),
(131551,    64925,  -2.30,  291,    '2015-07-22 11:08:48'),
(131564,    64928,  15.00,  293,    '2015-05-22 11:12:14'),
(131566,    64928,  -6.50,  293,    '2015-07-22 11:12:20'),
(131567,    64929,  -5.40,  293,    '2015-05-22 11:12:51'),
(131568,    64929,  1.90,   293,    '2015-06-22 11:12:57');
```

I'd like to select **ONLY** the rows that have **DIFFERENT PAIRS** of `idMemberCard` and `idAccount`

In this example, **131532** and **131533** would be **EXCLUDED** because the pair of 64924 and 292 are "linked to each other" only in these 2 rows.

Differently, **131534** and **131535** and **131551** should be **selected** because **64925** involves both the **292* and the **291** accounts

In other words, I'd like to select all the rows that relate "idMemberCard" and "idAccount" in different ( non unique ) idAccounts, so excluding the "idMemberCard" and "idAccount" pairs that only have a direct relation and no other historic correlations to other "idAccount"

**Expected output of the query:**

```
`idTransactions`,   `idMemberCard`, `idAccount`
131534,             64925,          292
131535,             64925,          292
131551,             64925,          291
131539,             64926           292
131540,             64926,          292
131541,             64926,          292
131550,             64926,          291
131544,             64928,          291
131545,             64928,          291
131564,             64928,          293
131566,             64928,          293
131567,             64929,          293
131568,             64929,          293
131546,             64929,          291
131547,             64929,          291
131548,             64929,          291
131549,             64929,          291
```

Comment: can you show the create table and the select query so we dont have to type it

Comment: @DrewPierce I already set it up: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd313a/4

Comment: thank you sir will give ya 5 min head start then look at it

Comment: @DrewPierce :-) No, go for it. I don't have time to work through it right now.

Comment: Not sure I'm following the question. Could you please share the output you'd like to get for this data? It would make the question much easier to understand.

Comment: @Mureinik shure, will add the output at the end of the question, gimme 2 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood the requirement correctly, the following should work:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM transactions t
JOIN (SELECT idMemberCard 
      FROM transactions
      GROUP BY idMemberCard
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT idAccount) > 1) g
  ON t.idMemberCard = g.idMemberCard
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd313a/6).

Equivalent queries are also possible using WHERE EXISTS, but I think this version should perform better in MySQL.

Comment: That's the one, the expected result matches!
One question: what indexes should I add to this table in order to keep this query running smooth on more than 1M rows? Are there any possible performance problems on such a large number of rows with this query?

Comment: @Maurizio: I suggest adding a covering index - one including both idMemberCard and idAccount - to your `transactions` table, and *checking* how the performance changes with it. As for performance problems, it depends on what performance you would consider problematic, what resources are available on your server, what the existing load on your server is already like, and so on.